# Efficient way to do large IN query in Google App Engine?

Tags: python, google-app-engine

A user accesses his contacts on his mobile device. I want to send back to the server all the phone numbers (say 250), and then query for any User entities that have matching phone numbers.

A user has a phone field which is indexed. So I do `User.query(User.phone.IN(phone_list))`, but I just looked at AppStats, and is this damn expensive. It cost me 250 reads for this one operation, and this is something I expect a user to do often.

What are some alternatives? I suppose I can set the User entity's id value to be his phone number (i.e when creating a user I'd do `user = User(id = phone_number)`), and then get directly by keys via `ndb.get_multi(phones)`, but I also want to perform this same query with emails too.

Any ideas?

Comment: Use a projection query instead of a normal query.

Comment: @dragonx I don't think that'll make a difference..a projection query is only cheaper on entities returned. It'd still have to pay a 1 read minimum for each contact in the list, summing to 250 reads + a small read for each projection returned..

Comment: It depends if you actually need the full User entity.  If you need the full entity, then projection queries will not help you.  If you only need certain properties, like the User ID or User name, using a projection query does not require read ops, just a small op per entity.

Comment: @dragonx well I just need to know if the entity exists or not for a given phone number. You're saying this wont cost me 1 read for every item in my phone list?

Comment: Just try it.  Another option is to use a keys only query, which also just uses small ops.  It's just another variation of a projection query.

Comment: @dragonx I get a "cannot use projection on a property with an equality filter" error

Comment: Check out the limitations on projections: https://developers.google.com/appengine/docs/python/datastore/projectionqueries#Limitations_on_Projections  A keys-only query might be easier than to rework your query.

Comment: @dragonx ya all these are good optimizations for getting results back. What I'm more concerned about is just the query itself that searches 300 contacts (most of which will probably get no results back), so that's what I want to somehow optimize

Comment: A datastore query is the optimal way to do that.  It doesn't search through entities, it walks through a predefined index and just returns the results of the index.  A normal query will find the result in the index, and then fetch the actual entity.  A key-only query or projection query just returns the data in the index without fetching the entity.

Comment: let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/18310/discussion-between-dragonx-and-mohabitar)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You could create a PhoneUser model like so:

```
from google.appengine.ext import ndb

class PhoneUser(ndb.Model):
  number = ndb.StringProperty()
  user = ndb.KeyProperty()

class User(ndb.Model):
  pass

u = User()
u.put()

p = PhoneUser(id='123-456-7890', number='123-456-7890', user=u.key)
p.put()

u2 = User()
u2.put()

p2 = PhoneUser(id='555-555-5555', number='555-555-5555', user=u2.key)

result =  ndb.get_multi([ndb.Key(PhoneUser, '123-456-7890'), ndb.Key(PhoneUser, '555-555-5555')])
```

I think that would work in this situation. You would just have to add/delete your PhoneUser model whenever you update your User. You can do this using post hooks: https://developers.google.com/appengine/docs/python/ndb/modelclass#Model__post_delete_hook

Answer (score 0):

I misunderstood part of your problem, I thought you were issuing a query that was giving you 250 entities.

I see what the problem is now, you're issuing an IN query with a list of 250 phone numbers, behind the scenes, the datastore is actually doing 250 individual queries, which is why you're getting 250 read ops.

I can't think of a way to avoid this.  I'd recommend avoiding searching on long lists of phone numbers.  This seems like something you'd need to do only once, the first time the user logs in using that phone.  Try to find some way to store the results and avoid the query again.

Answer (score 0):

there is no efficient way to do an IN query.
so instead avoid it all together.

how?

invert the query, instead of finding all people that belong to *this* guys phone list.

try

finding all people that have this users phoneid in *their* list.

this however is not without some extra cost.
the phonelist for each user much be stored and indexed.

```
class User(ndb.Model):
  phoneList = ndb.PropertyList()
  phone_id= ndb.StringProperty()

select from where User.phoneList = :this_phone_number
```