# Hosting a small database aside from Google App Engine?

Tags: python, database, google-app-engine

I asked [another question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12976652/efficient-way-to-do-large-in-query-in-google-app-engine) about doing large queries in GAE, to which the answer was pretty much not possible.

What I want to do is this: from an iOS device, I get all the user's contacts phone numbers. So now I have a list of say 250 phone numbers. I want to send these phone numbers back to the server and check to see which of these phone numbers belong to a User account.

So I need to do a query: `query = User.query(User.phone.IN(phones_list))`

However, with GAE, this is quite an expensive query. It will cost 250 reads for just this one query, and I expect to do this type of query often.

So I came up with a crazy idea. Why don't I host the phone numbers on another host, on another database, where this type of query is cheaper. Then I can have GAE send a HTTP request to my other server to get the desired info.

So I have two questions:

1. Are there any databases more streamlined to handle these kinds of
   queries, and which it would be more cheaper to do? Or will it all be
   the same as GAE?
2. Is this overkill? Is it a good idea? Should I suck it up and pay the cost?

Comment: Aside from the technical part.. who would like to share all the phone numbers in just another app? Are you sure your users have no problem with that? Especially if they will know that these phone numbers are not only on GAE, but also in another service...? Just something to think of from the privacy point of view..

Comment: @Lipis it's not another service, it's just another database that organizes the information. Just like say how Google or facebook has information stored on servers across the world..

Comment: have you tried putting it all into memcache, and invalidating it when it's updated otherwise just trying memcache first. Users who use the service often will typically keep their date in memcache, ideally.

Comment: @PaulC well I don't actually need the contacts stored, I just need to see if any of the user's contacts are registered users of the same app. And anyone can register at any given time, so this information can change at any moment

Comment: sure, but when you for example register a new user you can drop those details into memcache. Then when you need the data try memcache first, if it's there you've saved some reads. If not, read it them cache it again. And if the information changes just update memcache. Just an idea :)

Comment: @PaulC to be honest I never understood how memcache works. They give you a small amount of megabytes to be shared across the whole system - how are you supposed to store enough info in there? You're saying I can store 100,000 user account info in memcache and it would be ok?

Comment: @PaulC also, using NDB, isn't memcache handled automatically?

Comment: No, I'm saying that you can store the top N% of user accounts in Memcache, saving calls when that data is retrieved from memcache rather then the data store. I'm sure if you plot usage vs users you'll find 20% of users accounting for 80% of the usage, so perhaps 20% will fit in memcache. In any case, if you want to save reads then checking memcache is very useful and like I say you can invalidate a given memcache entry when new or updated data arrrives.

Comment: NDB handles some aspects of memcache automatically, but it won't cache IIRC queries. If you can get by key instead I believe that is cached.

Comment: This is a very strange operation to do frequently.  I would imagine you need to check 250 phone numbers once per user, the first time they log in.  Afterwards, you should only check one or two new phone or removed numbers against the list of of 250 numbers you already know about (that you stored somewhere after their first login).

Comment: @dragonx well what it is is that I want to check if any of the users contacts have started using the service. And this is subject to change often. If I have 300 contacts, and I check which of the 300 are using the same service, maybe today it will be only 5, but tomorrow, 2 more may have joined, and its important to get those 2 new users.

Comment: Within a User entity, you can store a list of all their contact numbers.  Then when you add a new User, you can search for all the other users that have them, you can update those users at this point.  So when a new User joins, you will need to do two relatively expensive queries - All the new User's contacts, and all the people that he's a contact of.  However, you still really just need to do this once every time a user joins.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

GAE's datastore should be good enough for your service. Since your application looks like could be parallelized very well.

## 1. use phone number as `key_name` of `User`.

As you set number as key_name of User, the following code will increase the query speed and reduce the read operation.

```
memcache.get_multi([phone_number1, phone_number2 ... ])
db.get([number1_not_found_in_memcache, number2_not_found_in_memcache])

memcache.set_multi("all_number_found_in_db")
```

## 2. store multi number in one datastore.

the operation cost of GAE not directly related to the entity's size. therefore a large entity store multi data would be another way to save the operation cost.

for example, store several phone number which have the same number_prefix together.

```
class Number(db.Model):
    number_prefix = db.StringProperty()
    numbers = db.StringListProperty(indexed = False)

# check number 01234567, 032123124
numbers = Number.get(["01", "03'])

# check 01234567 in number[0].numbers ?
# check 032123124 in number[1].numbers ?
```

this method could further imporve with memcache.

Comment: An entity is limited to 1mb in size. Is this a problem? Also, I need to do the same query by email, so I can't set the key_name to phone, because I need a general solution where I query a large set, such as phone numbers, emails, facebook ids, twitter ids, etc

Comment: 1) The entity size could be limited by dividing the phone numbers with  smaller pockets. 2) The datastore itself is the general solution you are looking for. To further improve the read operations, the data need to be denormalized.

Answer (score 0):

Generalizing slightly on other ideas offered... assuming that all your search keys are unique to a single User (e.g. email, phone, twitter handle, etc.)

At User write time, you can generate a set of SearchIndex(...) and persist that. Each SearchIndex has the key of the User.
Then at search time you can construct the keys for any SearchIndex and do two ndb.get_multi_async calls. The first to get matching SearchIndex entities, and the second to get the Users associated with those index entities.

Comment: I'm not really understanding what you mean..how would the search work? How many reads would I have to do?